# Multiple insect psychology

Tags: science-based, biology, psychology, insects

So I am making up a human that has been hybridized with some insect species and I was wondering what the psychological consequences of these separate minds being put together would be (of course the human mind is the dominant one, but the others influence in more subtle ways)?

Here is a list if the animals that he is hybridized with:

- Garden Tiger Moth
- Bombardier beetle
- Blue Dasher Dragonfly
- Ear Wig
- whichever termites have the fontanellar gun

Comment: Not certain if insects are even sapient. We know for sure that dogs think, but do ear wigs? Or are they just little deterministic bundles of instincts?

Comment: Basically what Jakob Lovern says - I don't think "mentality" is the right word.

Comment: @jdunlop okay I'll change it

Comment: To clarify, I don't think "mind" works either - it assumes any sort of parity between the bundle of instincts that likely makes up an insect's existence and the consciousness that makes up the human mind.  It's like asking "what would happen if we combined this planet with this galaxy?" - a difference of scale.

Comment: How...Kafkaesque.

Comment: sounds like an expert from terra formars .https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terra_Formars

Answer (score 2):

The real outcome of this experiment would be non-viable embryos that died in the petri dish before they could grow into fetuses, but for fictions sake lets assume that the issue of non-compatible bio-chemistry, crippling cancers, and contradictory self-terminating genetic codes were overcome.

Your going to have a sentient organism that has no place in nature or societey. It will be reviled and hated by people, and unable to emotionally cope because its capacity for intellect and emotions are blunted by the fact that its constantly distracted by vestigial instinctive urges. Insects dont posess minds, theyre basically instinctive and reflexive, responding with genetically inherent behaviors to various environmental stimuli.

Its basically a classic frankenstein's monster scenario. Its going to be a pathetic and tragic charecter that quite literally has no place it could possibly belong. It exists outside of both mankind and nature.

Answer (score 0):

### On a positive note . . .

This could be a fun story. Of course, it's been done with *The Fly* in [1958](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fly_(1958_film)) and in [1986](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fly_(1986_film)).

Star Trek TNG had an episode with a similar theme with the [crew members "devolving."](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Genesis_(episode)) (Stupid premise, if you ask me.)

It sounds like you're expanding the story, using more insect species. Interesting.

### But, why?

Perhaps you've got the rationale behind doing such a strange thing, I'm interested in what ideas you've come up with. I think knowing why would help begin to answer the question of the psychological ramifications of the new creatures. Mostly because, if the genetic science is advanced enough to "hybridize" humans with the species you list, why wouldn't the scientists simply give the hybrids the physical characteristics, and not the psychological changes? I mean . . . wouldn't the bug people be mostly subject to id desires (mating/eating/sleeping)?

Say more about the rationale behind the project. (Evil mad scientist? Creating hyper-alert soldiers? Simply an accident? << Unlikely.)

Comment: Well the main reason I want to have it is because I want their to be a cost to the power that the insect hybridization gave him and as for the in story reason well it gets a bit messy but a race of insectivores similar to humans was driven under ground and was never allowed to prosper like the humans could, so from this they developed a hatred and inferiority complexes towards humans which lead to them stealing tech from the humans, expanding on it and using advanced crisper and genetic code calculating super computer to mix dozens of humans with insect DNA and munch on them with insect brains

Comment: Um. What? I dunno what to say. The whole premise sounds highly unlikely and I would have trouble suspending my disbelief. Just my 0.02.

Comment: What makes it sound unlikely

Comment: @user45751: Anytime you insert a plot convenience into the story, it has to make sense. So, the insectivores don't like humans. They want to steal technology from them, ostensibly to destroy them. Well, why not steal nukes and fry the humans? Lots easier. Plus, the insects get the bonus of being able to survive radiation better than human beings. Your solution is unnecessarily complex.

Comment: but they don't just want to destroy humans they want to make them pay for their successes and reduce the humans to bugs

Comment: @user45751: This discussion is better placed in a chat. Regarding world building, the rationale seems petty and misplaced. But that's just my opinion. I might be wrong. Peace!